Картинка JS из разных директорий
У меня есть сайт на html, и java скрипт который делает рабочий выпадающий список, и он использует картинки стрелочек, скрипт расположен в корне, и есть много разных страниц в каталогах на уровни выше, на основной странице стрелочки отображаются, а на других страницах которые находятся в других папках ничего не рисуется
пример расположения:
/documentation/cbaseplayer/base_page.html
if (body && h5) {
       if(body.style.display == "none")
       {
          body.style.display = "block"
          
          h5.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/arrow-down.png')"; 
          h5.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
       }
       else
       {
          body.style.display = "none"
          
          h5.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
          h5.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/arrow-right.png')"; 
       }
    }

и такой вопрос, можно ли как то решить чтобы он автоматом добавлял '.../' в путь и стрелочки всегда находились?

Правильный подход тут уже сто лет такой:
Нужно в CSS прописать специальные классы, например .arrow-left/.arrow-right. А в JS всего лишь надо добавить этот класс элементу или удалить (element.classList.add / element.classList.remove).
Всё остальное страдание фигнёй давно нерелевантно
В таком случае в CSS всегда будет правильный путь до картинок, а JS очистится от бесполезного мусорного кода
